# Artificial intelligence for targeting 3D flying objects

Tags: xna-4.0, ai

I'm working on a 3D game in Xna in which there is my jet which I am controlling. I want to add other jets as enemies. For that I need their AI so that I could have them able to target my jet. I've searched Google but couldn't find good resources. I hope professionals here can help me with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the simplest way to achieve this is to give your enemy jets some steering behavior. Particularly the a pursuit steering algorithm, with some avoidance Autonomous and follow behaviors tied in. There's an excellent paper on [Steering Behaviors For Autonomous Characters](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/). With it you'll be able to glean the information needed to implement steering in your own game. I recommend starting with basic pursuit steering and evolving it from there. Using an offset pursuit algorithm will ensure you don't have enemy airplanes kamikaze-ing into you. Something like this:

[image]

Where your plane is the center of the white circle.

You can see a live example of a similar behavior [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/LeaderFollow.html). Also giving a enemy jet the flee behavior when they're targeted will make it a little more challenging to hit. (Have them flee from the firing cylinder that represents the kill zone in front of your plane)